# Performance in an SSIS package with multiple Conditional Split Components

Tags: sql, ssis

I am using conditional splits to validate data and send bad data down an alternate path in my package.  My conditional split code is similar to this:

(Gender != "M" ||Gender != "F" ||Gender != "U") == FALSE 
(Gender == "M" ||Gender == "F" ||Gender == "U") == TRUE

If the value is true I pass control to another conditional split or if false I will redirect that row to an error table.

I am using 25 conditional splits in a single package and I want to know if this is a good thing to do from a performance perspective.  How is the performance of using conditional splits as opposed to using another method to validate data?

I have added another scenario but its not working in conditional split. Please find the below information

I have allowed date values only this format and this period '01/01/1753' to '12/31/9000'

**My Conditions**

(Dob Varchar(10))

SUBSTRING(Dob,1,2) <= "12" && SUBSTRING(Dob,4,2) <= "31" && (SUBSTRING(Dob,7,4) >= "1753" || SUBSTRING(Dob,7,4) <= "9000") ==  TRUE

SUBSTRING(Dob,1,2) > "12" || SUBSTRING(Dob,4,2) > "31" || SUBSTRING(Dob,7,4) < "1753" || SUBSTRING(Dob,7,4) > "9000" ==  FALSE

My Input - 12/32/1990, 13/15/2000, 12/31/2010,01/01/1753,12/31/9000,12/31/9001,01/01/9001
Expected Output - 12/31/2010,01/01/1753,12/31/9000

But all the records considered as false in my conditions. 
Kindly give the solution for this scenario.

Comment: Please put more detail into your question - currently it isn't possible to give you an answer

Comment: Validate what data, and in what way? How many do you require? What would make the performance acceptable? The question needs to set out some sort of context...

Comment: E.g., In Conditional Split - 1.(Gender != "M" ||Gender != "F" ||Gender != "U") == FALSE  2.(Gender == "M" ||Gender == "F" ||Gender == "U") == TRUE  If the value is true i have to checked another condition or False i will moved to error table.

Comment: I have created one package. I have validate data using conditional split, In this package i used 25 conditional split. Is this performance wise good or not. My friend told to me it's improved more performance. Any body guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As William Todd Salzman has indicated, testing is the only way you will determine what is the optimal setup for *your* package. Generally speaking however, as counter-intuitive as it may seem, the less you do in a particular component, the faster SSIS can make it. The reason for this is the way the SSIS engine can determine parallelism - if it can determine column B is not manipulated in Derived column 1, then it can safely start making changes to that value in Derived Column 2.

- [Can different combinations of components affect Dataflow performance?](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2011/01/12/investigation-can-different-combinations-of-components-effect-dataflow-performance.aspx)
- [Increasing Throughput of Pipelines by Splitting Synchronous Transformations into Multiple Tasks](http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/technicalnotes/archive/2010/08/18/increasing-throughput-of-pipelines-by-splitting-synchronous-transformations-into-multiple-tasks.aspx)

Given your scenario, I would look to create multiple Derived Column Transformations that define your various boolean checks. For example, I'd create one field that indicates whether we have a valid gender like this.

Add a Derived Column Transformation named `DFT IsGenderValid` and I'd configure it thus

- IsGenderValid
- "add as new column"
- Gender != "M" || Gender != "F" || Gender != "U"
- DT_BOOL

I would then have a Conditional Split transformation operating on boolean value if for no other reason than I have *one* place to test, correct and maintain logic.

Repeat this pattern for as many validations as your business logic requires.

Comment: Can you give some example . If condition is matched how to pass description in derived column. For If gender not matched i will pass message "Invalid Gender".

Answer (score 3):

The best way to determine this is to create the same package twice, once where you validate this way, and then once where you validate in another way.  You can use BIDS with [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/) to run each of the packages by right clicking on the package and choosing Execute and Visualize Performance from the context menu.  Once you have done this, post the results as an answer so that others can benefit from your work!